# SpringBoot does not find views

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I'm trying to write a simple SpringBoot Web Application to get started with the framework.

This is my structure:

```
src
`-main
   `-java
   `-resources
     `-static
     `-templates
   `-webapp
     `-WEB-INF
        `-jsp
            `-login.jsp
```

I have a Controller like

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String loginMessage(){
        return "login";
    }
}
```

I've configurated the path where views has to be looked for in the `application.properties` like:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
```

I've also included the next dependency in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

But when I go to http://localhost:8080/login I'm still having a 404 error.
What am I missing?

EDIT:
Here is the log from the IntelliJ Idea console. It seems like it finds the login.jsp, but for some reason return an error page.

```
2018-07-06 11:17:20.488 DEBUG 53340 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/login]
2018-07-06 11:17:20.488 DEBUG 53340 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /login
2018-07-06 11:17:20.488 DEBUG 53340 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public java.lang.String com.albertocastano.apringboot.web.springbootfirstwebapplication.controller.LoginController.loginMessage()]
2018-07-06 11:17:20.488 DEBUG 53340 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/login] is: -1
2018-07-06 11:17:20.489 DEBUG 53340 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Requested media types are [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8] based on Accept header types and producible media types [*/*])
2018-07-06 11:17:20.489 DEBUG 53340 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver  : No matching bean found for view name 'login'
2018-07-06 11:17:20.489 DEBUG 53340 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Returning [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView: name 'login'; URL [/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp]] based on requested media type 'text/html'
2018-07-06 11:17:20.489 DEBUG 53340 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView: name 'login'; URL [/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-07-06 11:17:20.492 DEBUG 53340 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'login'
2018-07-06 11:17:20.492 DEBUG 53340 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp]
2018-07-06 11:17:20.492 DEBUG 53340 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp
2018-07-06 11:17:20.493 DEBUG 53340 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp]
2018-07-06 11:17:20.495 DEBUG 53340 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Matching patterns for request [/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp] are [/**]
2018-07-06 11:17:20.496 DEBUG 53340 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : URI Template variables for request [/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp] are {}
2018-07-06 11:17:20.497 DEBUG 53340 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapping [/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/], ServletContext resource [/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@3f0408]]] and 1 interceptor
2018-07-06 11:17:20.498 DEBUG 53340 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp] is: -1
2018-07-06 11:17:20.499 DEBUG 53340 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2018-07-06 11:17:20.499 DEBUG 53340 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
2018-07-06 11:17:20.500 DEBUG 53340 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
2018-07-06 11:17:20.501 DEBUG 53340 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/error]
2018-07-06 11:17:20.502 DEBUG 53340 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /error
2018-07-06 11:17:20.502 DEBUG 53340 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)]
2018-07-06 11:17:20.502 DEBUG 53340 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/error] is: -1
2018-07-06 11:17:20.522 DEBUG 53340 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Requested media types are [text/html, text/html;q=0.8] based on Accept header types and producible media types [text/html])
2018-07-06 11:17:20.522 DEBUG 53340 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Returning [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView@bd7588] based on requested media type 'text/html'
2018-07-06 11:17:20.522 DEBUG 53340 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Rendering view [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView@bd7588] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-07-06 11:17:20.522 DEBUG 53340 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
```

Comment: Is your controller correctly scanned and registered by Spring (check logs on startup) ? Is your `application.properties` inside `src/main/resources` ?

Comment: @Thoomas The controller is correctly scanned. 2018-07-06 11:24:55.351  `INFO 58696 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/login]}" onto public java.lang.String com.albertocastano.apringboot.web.springbootfirstwebapplication.controller.LoginController.loginMessage(java.lang.String)` And my `application.properties` is correctly placed.

Comment: Do you have the javax.servlet.jstl dependancy in your pom.xml ?    `<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>`

Comment: The scope of `tomcat-embed-jasper` is marked as `provided`. You have a container which provides it ?

Comment: @Thoomas I hadn't, I added the dependency but nothing changed. I've the dependency `<dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId> </dependency>` which I thought it would provides it. I just deleted that and everything works. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome, I'll post this as an answer for future readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing dependancy in your `pom.xml` file.

Add jstl :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And remove the scope `provided` of `tomcat-embed-jasper`, because it's not provided by default by any spring-boot-starter.